# Java Spring classpath :Spring does not find properties file in the class path

Tags: java, spring, classpath

We would like to keep the `.properties` file out of the jar so that we can change the properties used in a module and we do not have to re-install the module.

Before Java 8, we used to run a script and include the `.properties` file in the way below and it worked. But since when we updated to Java 8 , this way of including `.properties` file in classpath is not working, means java program fails not finding the `.properties` file.

The script looks like:

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -d64 -Xms1G -Xmx16G -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -cp "/online/sand/lib/client-api-1.0.0.jar:/online/sand/oap_pub/lib/*:/online/sand/oap/oap_dw/run/client_api/application.properties" team.online.client.api.MasterProcessor  | tee -a client_api.log
```

We are using Sping context to pick up the properties file this way:

```
<util:properties id="app_props"
                 location="classpath*:/application.properties" />
```

Then a property in that appilcation.properties files is being used ( in many different files) this way:

```
@Value( "#{app_props[\"SERVICE_PATH_GET_METADATA\"]?:''}" )
private String metadataServicePath;
```

**Question is :**

Does **Spring** sees **only the jar files** in "classpath*:/ ?

As when I am using the code below to see what is in **Spring's classpath** :

```
ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(new DefaultResourceLoader());
Resource[] resources = new Resource[0];
try {
    resources = patternResolver.getResources("classpath*:*");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (Resource resource : resources) {
   System.out.println("spring context classpath : " +resource.getDescription());
}
```

I am **NOT** seeing the `application.properties` in the classpath. And looks like files in jars are visible for Spring in classpath.

But if I print  using ClassLoader like this way:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

for (URL url: urls) {
    System.out.println("classloader classpath : " + url.getFile());
}
```

I am seeing this in the classpath :

```
/online/sand/oap/oap_dw/run/client_api/application.properties
```

Any insight on why is this difference between these two prints?

How can I include this `application.properties` file in the Spring classpath?

Answer (score 0):

To find your properties file, just specify the directory without the properties filename. java expects jars or directories on the classpath, not files.

Try
    ... -cp /online/sand/lib/client-api-1.0.0.jar:/online/sand/oap_pub/lib/*:/online/sand/oap/oap_dw/run/client_api/ team.online.client.api.MasterProcessor ...

BTW: the asterisk is not expanded if part of a string surrounded by double quotes. If there are no blanks in jar filenames, just strip the double quotes.